# Resize "area" Tags Dynamically in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

Recently I have been working on a kind of interactive image where I needed to map the image and create areas.

I noticed that they do not change dynamically. I created a simple code that change the  coords dynamically. I want to hear your thoughts about it since I searched a lot by did not find any related codes.

```
const getArea = document.querySelectorAll("area");
const getimg = document.querySelector(".myImg");
getArea.forEach(function (area) {
  const scaleWidth = getimg.width / getimg.naturalWidth;
  const scaleHeight = getimg.height / getimg.naturalHeight;
  coords = area.coords.split(",");
  const x = coords[0];
  const y = coords[1];
  const width = coords[2];
  const height = coords[3];
  area.coords = `${x*scaleHeight},${y*scaleWidth},${width* scaleWidth},${height* scaleHeight}`;
});
```

Comment: looks good but make sure that the image and other things are loaded before execution reaches forEach loop.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+resize+area+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: Thanks, @Ankit.
 I added the js file at the end of the HTML file to make sure that all other elements are available